# Extract all "name" values from json array in Redshift

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, amazon-redshift

I have a json field with values:

```
[{"elementId": "1", "name": "foo", "value": "A"}, {"elementId": "2", "name": "bar", "value": "B"}, {"elementId": "3", "name": "foobar", "value": "C"}, {"elementId": "4", "name": "barfoo", "value": "D"}]
```

So my data set would look like:

```
user_id | form_data
---------------------------------------------
101 | [{"elementId": "1", "name": "foo", "value": "A"}, {"elementId": "2", "name": "bar", "value": "B"}, {"elementId": "3", "name": "foobar", "value": "C"}, {"elementId": "4", "name": "barfoo", "value": "D"}]
102 | [{"elementId": "1", "name": "crash", "value": "A"}, {"elementId": "2", "name": "bang", "value": "B"}, {"elementId": "3", "name": "wallop", "value": "C"}]
```

I would like to extract the "name" values from the list such that I would have a comma separated list column as the output:

```
user_id | names
----------------------------
101 | foo,bar,foobar,barfoo
102 | crash,bang,wallop
```

The list can be of varying length, so my current approach (below) isn't going to work with longer forms:

```
SELECT a || ',' || b || ',' || c || ',' || d
FROM (select f.form_data
      ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_extract_array_element_text (f.form_data,0),'name') a
      ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_extract_array_element_text (f.form_data,1),'name') b
      ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_extract_array_element_text (f.form_data,2),'name') c
      ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_extract_array_element_text (f.form_data,3),'name') d
      FROM forms f)
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

I can extract all the name values as separate columns using the above - but the issue here is that i have to reference each indexed position "name" could appear in - and this doesn't scale.

What i'm trying to achieve would be to extract all the "name" components into one cell, without out referencing a position in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this update I think you are just looking to expand the json array and then aggregate the names into a list.  Does this meet your needs?

```
with num1024 as (
SELECT 
    (p0.n + p1.n*2 + p2.n * POWER(2,2) + p3.n * POWER(2,3) + p4.n * POWER(2,4) + p5.n * POWER(2,5) 
        + p6.n * POWER(2,6) + p7.n * POWER(2,7) + p8.n * POWER(2,8) + p9.n * POWER(2,9))::int as n
  FROM 
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p6,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p7,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p8,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p9
  Order by 1
)
select id, listagg(a, ',') within group (order by depth) as names
from (
        select f.id
              ,JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_extract_array_element_text (f.form_data,n.n),'name') a
              ,n.n as depth
        FROM forms f, num1024 n
        where a <> '' )
group by id
order by id
;
```

It works up to 1024 array elements.

Comment: Yep that gets exactly what i'm looking for, thank you! 

I'm not quite sure I follow what you're doing in the CTE though?

Comment: The CTE is just making a virtual table of the numbers between 0 and 1023.  There are lots of ways to make this but this one doesn't make assumptions about what else you have on your cluster.  Since this only has 1024 numbers that is the longest array that this query can fully extract.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a use case for RECURSIVE CTEs.  Take a look at this example as it seems to be nearly what you want - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that is what I'm looking for - I think the main issue I'm having is being able to extract the data from the json array/list in the format id like to - without having to check each index position individually.

I've edited the main post to try to reflect this